# Error while inserting on a DataSet

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

When i try to insert some String data on a TClientDataSet, I keep getting the

> DataSet not in Edit or Insert mode.

error. I have some other String fields on the Dataset, but it happends only with one field. The field named "data".

Here is the code of the creation of the Dataset

```
with FdsCabecalho.FieldDefs do begin
    Add('id', ftInteger);
    Add('empresa', ftInteger);
    Add('data', ftString, 100 );
    Add('idCliente', ftInteger);
    Add('nomeCliente', ftString, 100);
    Add('idVendedor', ftInteger);
    Add('total', ftFloat);
    Add('totalDesconto', ftFloat);
    Add('frete', ftFloat);
    Add('codigouMov', ftString, 100);
    Add('assinaturaCliente', ftString, 255);
end;
FdsCabecalho.CreateDataSet;
```

And here is the code of the insertion:

```
with FdsCabecalho do begin
    Append;
    FieldByName('id').AsString := IntToStr(frmMain.dmDados.getIDCabecalho(frmMain.empresa, idOrcamento));
    FieldByName('empresa').AsInteger := frmMain.empresa;
    FieldByName('data').AsString := data; {When the execution passes this line the error happends}
    FieldByName('codigouMov').AsString := idOrcamento;
    FieldByName('idCliente').AsString := nCliente.ChildNodes.Nodes['alternativeIdentifier'].Text;
    FieldByName('nomeCliente').AsString := nCliente.ChildNodes.Nodes['description'].Text;
    FieldByName('idVendedor').AsString := nVendedor.ChildNodes.Nodes['alternativeIdentifier'].Text;
end;
```

The 'data' variable is a String, that returns a 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss' date, in String format.

Already checked and the Dataset.State is dsInsert when the code reaches that line. If I comment that line, the rest of it works just fine.
It happens only with that field. Already asked some partner developers and they also don't know why that happens.

Comment: Where is the `.Post`?

Comment: Does FdsCabecalho have a `Data` property? Try it without using `with FdsCabecalho do`

Comment: @kobik The .Post is after some other code.. The error happens while trying to set the value of the field... Not on the Post statement.

Comment: @DavidA yep, that solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: just for information: `TCustomClientDataSet` has public property `Data : OleVariant`

Comment: @ValMarinov yeah, I've realized it after I posted the question... the Data variable was conflicting with the property inside the With...do clause... Removed it from the clause and it worked like a charm.